# How to test the quality of a word embedding?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, gensim

I have trained a word2vec model using GenSim 4.

The problem is that my corpus is quite small.

How can I test the quality of the word embeddings I have obtained?

Is there some standard measures to do that?

Comment: Theoretically, a w2v model is a NN model. I think you can evaluate it as the other machine learning models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to test your embedding is see how often your model agrees with the common consensus of how other embeddings complete word analogies. A collection of established word embedding analogies are [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/questions-words.txt).